# What ORMs Support SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, orm, sql-server-2012

Getting ready to start work on my next project and decided to use SQL Server 2012. The reason I am using sql 2012 is because it now supports sequences which is what I really need. In my research I found that [llblgen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) supports sql server 2012. Is there anymore out there that support it?

Comment: Entity Framework can just create SQL Server 2012 databases, but I don't know if it can utilize sequences.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what exactly you need supported?  It seems like you need sequence support outside of the pre-2012 scenarios (like identity columns), but it's not clear that LLBL Gen supports that (at least AFAICT).  What do you need to do with the sequence from your ORM?

Comment: The orm does not need to support sequences i can handle the sequence in raw sql query. I did not want to pay money for llblgen. I just need an orm that says it supports sql 2012.

Comment: 2012 Sequence support is coming in LLBLGen Pro v4 (which goes beta soon)

Answer (score 1):

SauceDB works just fine with Sql 2012. http://sauce.codeplex.com

disclamer: I wrote it